# Is it viable to play through the Witcher: Enhanced Edition relying heavily on magic?

Tags: the-witcher

Due to the recent release of the sequel, I have reinstalled The Witcher. I have previously played up to the end of the 2nd act but used very little magic.

Is it viable to play using mostly magic? If so, which signs/talents should I concentrate on?

If using swords with magic is more effective than just magic, I would still like to know which signs synergize well with sword talents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to complete the game with a sign heavy build. You'll still be using your sword, but with heavily developed Aard and Igni signs, you can get through most of the game with pretty minimal swordplay. Igni in particular is extremely potent at high levels.

Again, you won't be able to completely neglect your blades, but they become more a means of finishing off weakened foes, or a way to do a little damage while waiting on endurance to recharge, rather than your primary means of damage. Fortunately, you have enough Bronze talents to basically take everything, and enough Silver talents to maintain pretty reasonable competency with a few styles -  Strong Silver in particular, synergizes with Igni brilliantly.

Be warned, going Sign heavy *will* likely increase your dependence on Alchemy somewhat -  potions are a must for keeping your Endurance up.

Comment: *blinks*. I was about to ask about your strange terminology, but then I see the question is about The Witcher 1, not The Witcher 2. So, carry on, I guess.

Comment: My copy of Witcher 2 is waiting about 3 more weeks for me to have time to touch it, and I've mostly avoided spoilers. Care to tell me why my terminology seems odd?

Comment: Bronze / Silver talents are terms I'm not familiar with in relation to the Witcher 2